# HashMap sum algorithm

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my first attempt to use HashMap. Given is a table with n integers. Goal is to calculate in how many common subtables the sum of the numbers is x. I've been trying trying the following. Sample output is 2,10,4. I'm getting 2,10,2. Any idea where I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
public class FindSum {

  long count(int[] t, int x) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> totals = new HashMap<>();
    long count = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
      int value = t[i];
      sum += value;
      if (totals.containsKey(sum - x)) {
        count += totals.get(sum - x);
      }
      if (value == x) {
        count++;
      }
      totals.put(sum, totals.getOrDefault(sum, 0) + 1);
    }
    return count;
  }
}


Sample output:

FindSum f = new FindSum();

System.out.println(s.count(new int[] {1,3,2,4}, 4)); // 2

System.out.println(s.count(new int[] {0,0,0,0}, 0)); // 10

System.out.println(s.count(new int[] {1,-1,1,-1}, 0)); // 4
```

Comment: can u explain ur algoritm? i think order of input is important in ur algoritm

Comment: What do you mean by "_common_ subtable", most particularly the "common" part?